# Ubuntu x Nvidia drivers and secure boot - Failed to enroll new keys

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu install that I'm running on a drive other than my main Windows one and as far as I know, to install them on Ubuntu with secure boot enabled you need to enroll some sort of key (forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about; I'm new to this). When I go to add a password for this, it firstly doesn't ask for the password on next boot and when I look at the console output again, it says `Failed to enroll new keys.`

I have an HP machine which I have upgraded with a GTX 1050ti.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out it was a BIOS issue.

For anyone else, if they encounter this issue, make sure you change the key setting in your BIOS from HP keys only to custom keys.

Seems simple, but I didn't even know this was a setting.